# Открытие Custom AlertDialog после закрытия DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-xml, dialog

Возможно ли такое сделать, чтобы это корректно работало в Android 4.4? Это нужно для передачи даты в AlertDialog, ведь руками её писать пользователю будет не очень комфортно. Есть код, который работает на Android 5.0 и выше, а у меня Minimum SDK 4.4. На 4.4 AlertDialog после DatePickerDialog всплывает 2 раза независимо от каких либо условий. В этом и проблема :)

```
    private void DialogForKitKat(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay){
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_homework, null);
                    int monthlength = Integer.toString(monthOfYear).length();
                    String dayofweek = getDayOfWeek(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    if (monthlength == 1){dialogDate = dayofweek + ", " + dayOfMonth + "." + 0 + monthOfYear;}
                    else{dialogDate = dayofweek + ", " +  dayOfMonth + "." + monthOfYear;}
                    builder.setView(dialogView);
                    final TextView date_info = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_dialog);
                    date_info.setText(dialogDate);
                    final AutoCompleteTextView lesson_info = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_dialog);
                    final EditText dz_info = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.zadanie_dialog);
                    String[] array_predmets = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.predm);
                    List<String> predList = Arrays.asList(array_predmets);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, predList);
                    lesson_info.setAdapter(ad);
                    builder

                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    if (lesson_info.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 | dz_info.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Тебе нужно заполнить все поля", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } else {
                                        String predm = lesson_info.getText().toString();
                                        String work = dz_info.getText().toString();
                                    }

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }

                            });


                    builder.show();

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

Разметка второго AlertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="TextFields" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/lesson_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:dropDownHeight="120dp"
    android:hint="@string/predmet_dialog"
    android:maxLength="24"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zadanie_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/zadanie"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="300" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это [известный баг](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36951008), который исправили в Android 5.0. 
Как вариант, можно сделать проверку:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
    if (view.isShown()) {
        // ваше содержимое с формированием диалога и вызов его к показу
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли :) Теперь все правильно работает